# Dynamically enabling or disabling a widget does not work

Tags: android, widget

We would like to enable or disable widgets via code.  When we say 
"disable" we mean that a widget which is registered in an application 
should not show up in the list of widgets available to the user when 
they try to add a widget to their home screen. 
This question has been asked, unfortunately, many times without 
answer.

There was one response by Dianne Hackborn to a separate 
widget question which suggested that it was possible to use the 
package manager to disable widgets:

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager(); 
pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName("com.example.android.apis", ".appwidget.ExampleBroadcastReceiver"), 
    PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, // or DISABLED 
    PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

This, however, does not work.  The widget component will still appear 
in the list of widgets.  It may be that the AppWidgetService (located 
in the Android source's Base.git at \src\base\services\java\com\android 
\server), which loads the list of available widgets, caches this list 
of available widgets.  If that were the case, though, then the above 
code which enables or disables the widget component would work after a 
device reset because there would be no cache; it does not.

I have also tried looking into overriding some methods of the 
AppWidgetProvider, such as filtering out any events.  I don't think 
this will go anywhere, because the AppWidgetService, which populates 
the list, uses the Package Manager to find all components which catch 
the ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE action on startup and when a package is 
added (i.e. a new app is installed).  The only time that a provider is 
removed from this list is on a ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED broadcast. 
So given that the providers will always be there, regardless of the 
enabled/disabled state of the component, I have looked into the actual 
list activity which is shown from the Launcher app when the user long- 
clicks the desktop and adds a widget:  AppWidgetPickActivity in 
Settings.GIT in 
com.android.settings.  This, unfortunately, populates the list 
directly from the AppWidgetService, without any filtering for the 
component's enabled status: 
    void putInstalledAppWidgets(List items) { 
        List installed = 
mAppWidgetManager.getInstalledProviders(); 
        putAppWidgetItems(installed, null, items); 
    }

I would love to see if anyone has overcome this hurdle.  Perhaps I am 
going about it the wrong way.  All I want is to be able to remove a 
widget from the list of widgets available to the user when they try to 
add a widget to their home screen.

Comment: Any update with this issue after 3 years?

Answer (score 5):

> It may be that the AppWidgetService
>   (located in the Android source's
>   Base.git at
>   \src\base\services\java\com\android
>   \server), which loads the list of
>   available widgets, caches this list of
>   available widgets.

It does, near as I can tell. It stores the list in `mInstalledProviders`; this list is added to via `readStateFromFileLocked()`, which appears to be called from the system startup logic.

> If that were the case, though, then
>   the above code which enables or
>   disables the widget component would
>   work after a device reset because
>   there would be no cache; it does not.

You assume a RAM cache. The cache is an XML file.

> This, unfortunately, populates the
>   list directly from the
>   AppWidgetService, without any
>   filtering for the component's enabled
>   status

And this would appear to be a bug in Android. More generally, the whole caching thing I would think is the bug -- I see no way to recover if that cache gets out of sync.

I would recommend you post your writeup as an issue on the [public Android issue tracker](http://b.android.com), if you have not done so already.

Answer (score 3):

It worked for me!  I had to use DONT_KILL_APP or it would kill my app immediately.  Also, I had to comment out the condition to check if it was already in the same state.

Here's the helper method I created:

```
public void setMyCustomWidgetEnabled( boolean bEnable )
    {
        Log.d( LOG_TAG_NAME, "Entering setMyCustomWidgetEnabled( " + bEnable + " )..." );

        PackageManager rPackageManager = getPackageManager();
        if( rPackageManager != null )
        {
            ComponentName rComponentName = new ComponentName( getBaseContext(), MyCustomWidget.class );

            int nComponentEnabledState = rPackageManager.getComponentEnabledSetting( rComponentName );

            if( bEnable )
            {
                //if( nComponentEnabledState == PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED )
                {
                    // Change the State to Enabled
                    rPackageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting( rComponentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP );

                    Log.d( LOG_TAG_NAME, "-> Changed My Custom Widget' to ENABLED!" );
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //if( nComponentEnabledState == PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED )
                {
                    // Change the State to Disabled
                    rPackageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting( rComponentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP );

                    Log.d( LOG_TAG_NAME, "-> Changed 'My Custom Widget' to DISABLED!" );
                }
            }
        }

        Log.d( LOG_TAG_NAME, "Leaving setMyCustomWidgetEnabled( " + bEnable + " )..." );
}
```

Comment: It looks like the enable/disable works only when the receiver in the manifest is originally enabled. If it is disabled by manifest, the enable/disable programatically doesn't work. Please can you confirm this behaviour?

Comment: @peter.bartos Yeah, it only works if it's originally enabled in the manifest. Also for the app to disable the widget, the user needs to force quit the app in order to 'update' the widget list if it doesn't kill it programmatically.

Answer (score 3):

There's a bug in the [platform code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.4_r1.2/services/java/com/android/server/AppWidgetServiceImpl.java#1348) that causes the system to ignore widgets that are disabled in the manifest. **This is being fixed for Android 12**, but will still affect previous versions.

Your widget provider's receiver must be enabled in the manifest or else it will never be shown to the user.

```
<!-- DO NOT set android:enabled="false" on this receiver! -->
<receiver android:name="ExampleAppWidgetProvider" >
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
</intent-filter>
<meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
           android:resource="@xml/example_appwidget_info" />
```

As long as the widget is enabled by default, `PackageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting` will work to disable and re-enable it later.

You can register a receiver for [MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED) to disable this immediately for users on update of your app. To handle fresh installs, you'll want to add code elsewhere in your app to disable the widget the first time your app runs.

Comment: The commit that fixes this issue: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/85be035336af8d83eb24980026418207c85991cb%5E%21/#F0

Answer (score 0):

The feature

```
pm.setComponentEnabledSetting()
```

works in ICS.  When the widget is disabled, it's removed from the list of available widgets.  Small consolation for the moment, but it's at least been corrected.

Comment: This works as long as the widget provider receiver is not disabled by default